# WiFi connects, pings and DNS work, but no response to http [SYN]

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, router, http

I have a problem using WiFi on my Dell M4600 running Windows 7 x64. I'm using a Virgin Media Netgear Super Hub in the UK to connect to the internet. It works fine when I use a wired connection, but if I try to use WiFi I can't browse to any website.

I've tried to narrow things down to find out exactly where the fault lies, but I'm not getting very far. This is what I have tried, and know so far:

- Wired connection works, WiFi doesn't.
- Other devices work, my Mac Book Pro and iPhone can both use the same WiFi connection to browse websites.
- While connected on WiFi, PING and DNS works (which means the Win7 network troubleshooter can't find any problems).
- Using Wireshark, I can see that the http [SYN] packets do not get a response like they normally would when I compare with a trace on a wired connection.
- I've checked the router config, and made sure that there are no rules that block or limit anything.
- I switched off UPnP to see if that was causing a problem, it made no difference.
- I've tried both IE and Firefox, and checked their network settings to ensure that it wasn't set to use a proxy or something. Both browsers experience the same problem.
- I've tried temporarily disabling anti virus protection, but no difference.

I'm not sure what else to try. As other devices work with no problems, it would point to a problem with my laptop, but the wireshark trace shows that it's not getting a response to the http [SYN] which points to a router problem or something beyond the router. A wireshark trace showing an attempt at browsing to Google while on WiFi is shown below.

Does anybody have any idea what could be the problem, or what else to try?

[image: Wireshark trace]

Comment: try setting 802.11n to disabled

Answer (score 2):

For me similar problem was resolved in command line with commands:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /renew
```

In Vista/Win7 you need to run it as Administrator